# What is a good example of a subcontext?

Tags: word-usage

I understand what a context is but how can a context have a context?

Answer (score 1):

It is a context subordinate to the main context. It's a silly word, but it does have a meaning.

Consider Antony's speech from Julius Caesar by William Shakespeare.

Context:

Caesar has just been killed by Brutus who feared that Caesar would become a dictator soon. That's what Antony means when he repeats Brutus' accusation that Caesar "was ambitious." A friend of Caesar's, Antony uses the phrase sarcastically. That's how it all comes off - on the surface.

Subcontext:

It's a lot more complicated. Brutus is the only person there who sincerely believed he was preserving the Republic when he killed Caesar. All his supporters backed him for political gain only. That's what Antony implies when he says that they are "all, all honorable men." There's more to it: you might want to research it further.

The speech goes like this:

Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears.
I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him.
The evil that men do lives after them;
The good is oft interrèd with their bones.
So let it be with Caesar. The noble Brutus
Hath told you Caesar was ambitious.
If it were so, it was a grievous fault,
And grievously hath Caesar answered it.
Here, under leave of Brutus and the rest—
For Brutus is an honorable man;
So are they all, all honorable men—
Come I to speak in Caesar’s funeral.
He was my friend, faithful and just to me.
But Brutus says he was ambitious,
And Brutus is an honorable man.
He hath brought many captives home to Rome
Whose ransoms did the general coffers fill.
Did this in Caesar seem ambitious?
When that the poor have cried, Caesar hath wept.
Ambition should be made of sterner stuff.
Yet Brutus says he was ambitious,
And Brutus is an honorable man.
You all did see that on the Lupercal
I thrice presented him a kingly crown,
Which he did thrice refuse. Was this ambition?
Yet Brutus says he was ambitious,
And, sure, he is an honorable man.
I speak not to disprove what Brutus spoke,
But here I am to speak what I do know.
You all did love him once, not without cause.
What cause withholds you then to mourn for him?
O judgment! Thou art fled to brutish beasts,
And men have lost their reason. Bear with me.
My heart is in the coffin there with Caesar,
And I must pause till it come back to me. (weeps)